# Is there a JS event that gets fired when a subform row got moved / deleted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, subform

When Adding a subform row (in the backend) it fires the "subform-row-add" event that can be observed with JS.

I've tried default namings like "subform-row-moved", "subform-row-move", "subform-row-delete", "subform-row-deleted" without any success.

Is there any ressource or a hint where to find those events?
a list maybe?

Edit:
Ok I've checked the file (https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/e770fe3eae3bf7c762ddff2001443815fdf71c7a/build/media_source/system/js/fields/joomla-field-subform.w-c.es6.js) and found that the delete event is called "subform-row-remove" but no event got fired on moved (not seen in this file)

it looks like i need to observe it by myself then...